# When is $F[X]/(f)$ over $F$ an integral extension?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

I was looking at the concept of integral extension. So $K/F$ is integral means that for every $a \in K$ is the root of a monic polynomial with coefficient in $F$. For example $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not integral since $1/3$ is not the root of a monic polynomial with integral coefficients. I was wondering when the extension $F[X]/(f)$ over $F$ was an integral extension. I was suggested it is integral if and only if $f$ is a monic polynomial? Why? If I take for instance $[p]_f \in F[X]/(f)$ it is not a root of $f$ I think.

Comment: Or if its leading coefficient is a unit. That being said, to answer your question, $x\bmod f$ is a root of $f$.

Comment: @Bernard I also thought I should use $[x]_f$ is a root of $f$ but if I consider $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ for instance, and $[p]_f=[x+3]_f$, then $f([p]_f)=[x]_f^2+6[x]_f+[7]_f \neq 0$ no?

Comment: Why should $[x+3]$ be a root of $x^2-2$? Also, you can simplify further: $[x^2]_f+6[x]_f+[7]_f=6[x]_f+[9]_f$.

Comment: Oh, but so I didn't understand how "$[x]_f$ if a root of $f$" should help me.

Comment: Simple (I'll omit the index $f$): $f([x])=[f(x)]\equiv 0\mod f$.

Comment: But I have to show that any $[p]$ is the root of a monic polynomial. So what would be this monic polynomial for any $[p]$, if it is not $f$?

Comment: You can simply say that the set of integral elements is a subring, hence any polynomial in the integral element $[x]$ is itself an integral element.

Comment: Oh, I didn't looked at it like that. Now it is clear, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!